# How to detect the beginning of a frame in a DirectX application (>= D3D10)?

Tags: directx, direct3d

I 'm trying to extract various data from frames in a DirectX >= D3D10 application.

I can detect the end of a frame with IDXGISwapChain::Present() but  how to detect the beginning of a rendering frame ?

Thanks.

Comment: Detect in what sense? A frame as defined as the time between calls to ``Present``.

Comment: If you consider the call to Present as the end of the frame, then it's also the beginning of next frame :)